# Converting Date Time format in dataweave

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

I want to convert date in this format "Mon Feb 17 00:00:00 IST 2020" to "2020-02-27".How to convert it in dataweave in mule 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---    
payload as DateTime {format: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"} as String {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Comment: Hey I want to bulk insert into db but getting The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported. error even after converting date as you mentioned above.Any suggestions??

Comment: That's a different question than this one. You should post a new question for that issue. Please include the complete error message, the Mule 4 exact version, Database connector version and the XML of the Mule configurations and flow.

Comment: I am getting Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.I am attaching the payload in above question.Your suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: That's probably a different problem related to database types conversion which. This question was about pure DataWeave time format conversion. You should really ask a new question and add the relevant data I mentioned, to obtain an answer. Changing the question afterwards is not a good practice.

Comment: Sure I will do it